# Using LINQ on shapes

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to ask if it is possible to use LINQ to draw rectangles saved in list with a condition of drawing a specific rectangle inside that list. This is  a newbie question, so please bear with me.

Comment: LINQ is a querying technology that has nothing to do with drawing. Can you please expand your question to explain how you're storing the rectangles in a list?

Comment: LINQ = language integrated _query_. It had no ability to execute code, only to refine (when iterated) a list of elements into a different list of elements / a single item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name says, LINQ is for querying any kind of data. As long as you see objets as data carriers you can use LINQ to query them. But it can't do any drawing or any kind of code execution. If you divide your problem into two parts; first selecting the appropriate shapes and then drawing them, the code could be something like this:

```
    public void QueryShapes(IEnumerable<Shape> shapes)
    {
        var rectangles =
            from shape in shapes
            where shape is Rectangle
            let rect = (Rectangle)shape
            where rect.Width > 100 // conditions...
            select shape as Rectangle;

        rectangles.ToList().ForEach(Draw);
    }
    public void Draw(Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        // drawing
    }
```